# insert JsonArray key value data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to insert jsonarray data into mysql database. I am sending jsonarray to server using Android Application to a PHP script.
Following is the code I am writing for PHP side:

```
$jsonArray = $_REQUEST['data'];

$Array = json_decode($jsonArray);

foreach($Array as $row){

    foreach($row as $name => $phone){

        echo $name.':'.$phone;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO contact (Name, Phone_numbers) VALUES ('$name', '$phone')";
        $result_set = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

It saves `$name`s correctly, but doesn't save `$phone` (numbers) correctly.

Please anybody help me out.

thanks

Comment: So what "doesn't save phone numbers correctly" means? What happens with phone numbers?

Comment: Can you provide content of $jsonArray?

Comment: some random value its storing. and all are same

Comment: jsonArray is like ["abc" , "123" : 
"asdf" , "12345"    ] and so on

Comment: Why are you don't try print_r($jsonArray) and post to you question. It's clearly

Comment: Why would you use a database API that's been deprecated for 5 years? Don't do this.

Comment: What else should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would try then take a solution

```
$Array = json_decode($jsonArray,true);
```